# Will it affect bonding between me any my 5-month-old when she's unable to recognize me after I left her for 6 months?

Tags: infant, separation, bonding

I have a 5-month-old daughter. I left her for 6 months with my mom, my brother's family in India and they are really taking good care. She is playing and happy with them. Daily I will do video call but she is not remembering my face, voice nor does she even respond to me. Will that affect my bonding between mother and child. Someone please advice me.

Comment: Are you the mother? Does she respond to anyone on video calls that you know of, or are you the only videocaller? How long will it be before you can renter the baby's life on a permanent basis? Will that be in India, or will you take the child away from those she has grown dependent upon?

Comment: Hi anongoodnurse,I am the Mother.Even her father does Video call but she doesnt respond to it.It takes 6 months separation and this October she is coming back,yes she is in India and will be with us in canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression that you are not able to return to your child for the next six months. My advice is to not worry about it. Accept it. If you cannot change it, just prepare yourself for rebuilding your relationship with your child once you do return. The relationship between a parent and a child evolves so much over time anyway, and they are all different.

As for the video chats.. My children did not start meaningfully interacting with video calls until they were at least a year old. Up until that point, it's a screen. They don't know that it's a live picture vs a recording, and their senses are not developed to be able to relate a real physical person through a moving picture. I wouldn't worry about the perceived "not remembering" since it's more likely more "Why do I have this screen held in front of me when I want to play with blocks?".

Comment: Thank you Ian for your consoling words,much appreciated.I was worried that the bond between me and my child would be reduced.Since I saw in Google,that the child needs Mother pampering for the first 2 years.So I was much worried.